# How do I calculate the number of distinguishable arrangements of 3 objects A and 2 objects B in 8 boxes?

Tags: combinatorics

Just the title. Thank you in advance. 
How do I calculate the number of distinguishable arrangements of 3 objects A and 2 objects B in 8 boxes?
So far I've gotten to 
(3+2)!/3!2! Which is 10,
But I dont understand how to account for 8 boxes. I think they are distinguishable and only 1 can go in each box

Comment: Are the boxes distinguishable?

Comment: I believe so, but I wrote the question as i got it and it didn't really specify

Comment: Is there a limit to how many objects may be placed in the same box?  Where did you encounter this problem?  What progress have you made?  Where are you stuck.  Please [edit] your question accordingly.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Well I wonder stand how to get an answer by just assuming 8 boxes doesnt matter. So (3+2)!/3!2! Which is 10

Comment: @Johnhrethorne If every box can at most contain one object then first choose $3$ out of $8$ to contain an object A, then choose $2$ out of the remaining $5$ to contain an object B. Result: $\binom83\binom52$. However if a box can contain more than one object then this does not work.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what the $ means? I'm a bit new to stack exchange